# Connecting two power supplies with almost like voltages to an amplifier in parallel

Tags: power-supply, amplifier, 12v

I have recently been working on a custom sound system in my living room. For the subwoofer, I am using a 1000W amplifier. This is currently running off of a 12V computer power supply that outputs around 650W (The power supply shuts off at a certain volume because of lack of power). I have another power supply (not a computer power supply) that is 500W but has a voltage of 13.5V, not 12. I've read that this voltage is actually better for running car audio equipment and I am using another 13.5V power supply for the head unit to power the highs and mids.

I am wondering if it would be possible for me to connect these two power supplies in parallel to increase the power to this amplifier since they are both safe voltages. Would this be possible? Would I need to use a resistor to match voltages? Or is this just not a good idea altogether?

Update: This is car audio equipment so high power ratings should not be a shock.

Comment: All I can say is I pity your neighbours and I'm glad I don't live near you...

Comment: 650 W is not enough, for a *living room*!!? Turn down the volume and save your eardrums, and the annoyance of everyone else within 1/2 mile. Geesh!

Comment: @OlinLathrop Let me add some information. I am a college student who is a bass head and has parties. It is still a valid question that I wish I had an answer for.

Comment: @Majenko: You don't know if he lives near you.  He hasn't filled out the location in his profile.  I checked too.  I'll assume therefore he does live me and won't help him being a ass to everyone else in the vicinity.

Comment: Woah, 12V and 1000 Watts... ~80 amps??  What's the impedance of the sub-woofer?  Or is there a switching supply in the amp?    Do you have a link or model for the 13.5V supplies?  I've connected bench supplies in parallel for more current, but I'm not sure that fixed supplies are so forgiving.  A resistor or something (power diode?) for matching would be an idea.. but how much current/ power will it need to dissipate?

Comment: @OlinLathrop My reason for asking the question shouldn't deter you from answering. I live in townhouses which means I am surrounded by other college students who are generally the ones partying. I apologize for my question offending you in some way. So if you don't like the question, please don't visit this page.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold the load on the amp and subwoofer is 4ohms. So you're saying an idea would be to bring the fixed power supply's voltage down to 12v and connect it in parallel with a diode?

Comment: Well I was suggesting a diode in each power supply line for (maybe) two reasons.  The first is to protect the supplies when one gets turned on before the other.  and the second is to try and provide some load balancing.. I don't know how well that will work.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold I'll use this method then. Since I'm using diodes to control the flow of power, do I need to worry about making the fixed power supply 12v?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me put this as an answer rather than a continuation of comments.
Adding diode to supplies, something like [this](http://cdn.instructables.com/FPM/2ZPP/GOHM3X0M/FPM2ZPPGOHM3X0M.LARGE.jpg). Now you'll want some beefy diodes, maybe 30 to 60 amps.  And probably Schottkies, maybe something from this [page](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?pv96=24&FV=fff40015%2Cfff8007f%2Ce480025%2Ce480027%2Ce48003a%2Ce48003c%2Ce48003f%2Ce480041%2Ce480042%2Ce480043%2Ce480045%2Ce480052%2Ce48006c%2Ce48006d%2Ce4800d1%2Ce4800d2%2Ce4800d3%2Ce4800d4%2Ce480112%2Ce480117%2Ce480137%2Ce480138%2Ce48014a%2Ce48014c&k=diode&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25). With heat sinks.  RE: power supply adjustment.  Hopefully there is some adjustment so that you can set the voltage for each supply to be about equal.  (Actually you'll want the voltage after each diode under load to be equal.)  Getting exactly 12V is not important.

I do worry, that I'm giving advice to a musician and not an electronics "geek".  I hope you understand what you are doing.  Do you have a way to measure the voltage?  Do you know why I picked the diodes I did?  And why the heatsink?

Comment: I'm more of a musician but I do know what I'm doing. I have a multimeter so I am able to measure voltage. I know that I will need a 60 amp diode for the psu and 40 for the fixed because of Power=Volts*Amps. To be honest my original idea was adding diodes but I was hoping someone would say I didn't need to change the voltage.

Comment: @SpencerMay - if you connect a 12V supply and a 13.5V supply, in parallel and through diodes, the 13.5V supply, will supply all of the power to the load, until that supply is so overloaded that its output sags to 12V to match the other supply. Most likely, the 13.5V supply will shutdown or die first.

Comment: @DoxyLover so that means dropping the voltage to 12V before it passes through the diode is required? Thanks for that info.

Comment: @SpencerMay, 60A and 40A? Hmm you want to get about the same current from each supply.  If one is at 13.5 volts and the other 12 V, well the 12V one will do nothing.  The diodes will help balance things a little, but only to the ~50mV level.  The one issue is that when diodes get hot their forward voltage decreases.  Which means the one passing more current gets hotter.. and passes more current.    You can mount them near each other on the heatsink to minimize this, but...

Comment: @ George: Using diodes in series with individual supplies and then paralleling them at the outputs of the diodes is **never** a good idea unless the tempco of each supply-diode combo is positive.

Comment: @EMFields, I don't think there are any diodes with positive tmepco's.  But there will always be some resistance, and that should help balance things.  (But I've only done this with bench supplies which behave gracefully when too much current or voltage is asked from them.)

Comment: @George: Part 1.)That there are no diodes with positive tempco's is precisely the point, so for the entire system to be self-protecting each of the power supply systems **must** exhibit a positive tempco in order to prevent current hogging as temperature increases.  Such being the case, the supplies themselves must exhibit positive tempco's or, if series resistances are to be added, passively, they must exhibit a greater positive tempco than the supply they're protecting for balance ever to occur.

Comment: @George: Part 2.) So, considering just the expense, the loss of power to the load, and the OP's question: "Or is this just not a good idea altogether?" I'd have to answer with a resounding **YES**!